# Cannot invoke observeForever on a background thread when testing

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I'm testing my viewmodel and hilt implementation , i have set up the code but upon running the test it throws ex exception that i cannot run the observer on background thread , can anyone please help to figure out the issue , Thank you

- This is my testing class

```
 @HiltAndroidTest
@UninstallModules(AppModule::class)
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
class SimpleViewModelHiltTest {

    @get:Rule
    var hiltTestRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)


    @Inject
    lateinit var itemsDao: ItemsDao

    @Inject
    lateinit var simpleRepository: SimpleRepository


    lateinit var simpleViewModel: SimpleViewModel


    @Before
    fun setUp(){
        hiltTestRule.inject()
        simpleViewModel = SimpleViewModel(simpleRepository)
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown(){

    }

    

    @Test
    fun testCaseEmptyItemName_returnsErrorStatus() = runTest{
        val itemModel = ItemsModel("",23F,"California",1)
        simpleViewModel.insertItems(itemModel)
        val result = simpleViewModel.liveData.getOrAwaitValue()
        assertThat(result.getContentIfNotHandled()?.status).isEqualTo(Status.ERROR)
    }


    @Test
    fun testCaseEmptyItemPlace_returnsErrorStatus() = runTest {
        val itemModel = ItemsModel("Banana",23F,"",1)
        simpleViewModel.insertItems(itemModel)
        val result = simpleViewModel.liveData.getOrAwaitValue()
        assertThat(result.getContentIfNotHandled()?.status).isEqualTo(Status.ERROR)
    }


    @Test
    fun testCaseValidValues_returnsSuccessStatus() = runTest {
        val itemModel = ItemsModel("Banana",23F,"California",1)
        simpleViewModel.insertItems(itemModel)
        val result = simpleViewModel.liveData.getOrAwaitValue()
        assertThat(result.getContentIfNotHandled()?.status).isEqualTo(Status.SUCCESS)
    }


}
```

- Error thrown

```
Cannot invoke observeForever on a background thread
```